# Table creation - foreign key constraint incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I'm creating a database for a zoo for a project, and when I try to create the table "Lives" with a primary key from the table "Animals" i get an error

```
CREATE TABLE Department
    (DeptName       VARCHAR(35),
     DeptBuilding   VARCHAR(35),
     DeptBudget     VARCHAR(9),
     PRIMARY KEY(DeptName)
    );

CREATE TABLE Animals
    (AnimalID       CHAR(5),
     NameLatin      VARCHAR(35),
     DeptName       VARCHAR(35),
     AnimalType     VARCHAR(10),
     AnimalName     VARCHAR(10),
     PRIMARY KEY(AnimalID),
     FOREIGN KEY(DeptName) REFERENCES Department(DeptName) ON DELETE SET NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE Houses
    (HouseID        CHAR(5),
     HouseName      VARCHAR(35),
     TypeHouse      VARCHAR(10),
     DeptName       VARCHAR(35),
     PRIMARY KEY(HouseID), 
     FOREIGN KEY(DeptName) REFERENCES Department(DeptName) ON DELETE SET NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE Lives
    (AnimalID       CHAR(5),
     HouseID        CHAR(5),
     PRIMARY KEY(AnimalID, HouseID),
     FOREIGN KEY(AnimalID) REFERENCES Animals(AnimalID) ON DELETE SET NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY(HouseID) REFERENCES Houses(HouseID) ON DELETE SET NULL
    );
```

I expected it to create the table but i get: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Given that `AnimalID` is a column in the `PRIMARY KEY` of `Lives`, it's not possible to specify the setting the column to `NULL`. (The `PRIMARY KEY` constraint enforces a `NOT NULL` restriction on the columns in the primary key.)

Try `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. And then give it a whirl with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

If we omit the `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` clauses, the default action is `NO ACTION`, which as far as I can tell operate exactly as if we had specified  `RESTRICT`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense

Comment: Also consider naming tables in the *singular*, that is, naming what *one* row represents.  Looks like that pattern was started with `Department`.

Comment: I don't quite understand?